# Please I need testnet ether to run my code

Tags: testnets

my address is 0x8566428c5D15Ef06b2bCc1f6f8e1FbF9d3A0AfD5

I have tried using the Ethereum Ropsten Faucet but I have not received any money. I also tried mining all through the night as well.

Would appreciate this..

thanks

Comment: Have you tried http://ipfs.b9lab.com:8080/ipfs/QmQsrJAyf3vv7otNoiYDMzcVN31o62Hq22yr8df4LgdFmr/throttled_faucet.html Not more than 1 Ether / minute.

Comment: You have 2.7 eth on your account, how much do you need for your test?

Comment: This should really be a question along the lines of: _"Why am I not receiving ether from the Ropsten Faucet?"_. As it stands, there's no real question here, just a request for free ether :-)

Answer (score 1):

Can't help with Ropsten Ether, but if you're using go-ethereum, you can use the Rinkeby testnet too https://www.rinkeby.io/ which has a built in faucet.

Comment: We can also use Kovan testnet https://kovan.etherscan.io/ and corresponding faucet.